# withdrawing earnings

Tags: transactions

Do i need a license and certificate to withdraw earnings? I would like to withdraw my earnings from my wallet. I am being told that I need to pay $81k to get a certificate and license in order to withdraw my earnings.  Please provide with pertinent information.

Thank you